# Syntax error after upgrade from 1.8.x to 1.9.1 (and beyond)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

First post...full disclosure, I am not a web developer.

Our site was built some years back by outside vendor using Ruby on Rails 1.8.x. It's worked fine for many years, I know some stuff and have modified some things using HTMl, but know very little about Ruby. I've read some docs in the past few days but I am looking for some direction.

Our hosting site upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS to 14.04.5 LTS, and in the process Ruby as well, at which point my site started crashing. Using their docs, I've tried to move my installation to at least 1.9.1, and also as far as 2.4.x without success. I've followed their instructions for Gems and Bundler but no luck - my home page loads, but that's it. I've been fixing errors that I can as they occur, but I've hit a bit of a wall and I'm hoping for someone to just point me in the right direction. I was thinking it was an encoding error - I know Ruby has undergone some changes in the newer revs in that regard - but nothing I have tried seems to work.

In my boot.rb I get syntax errors on simply "&quot" - if I program around that I seem to get them farther down the line, so something isn't loading properly or I've installed something incorrectly:

```
    /home/<my site>/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:50: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')'
  plural(Regexp.new(&quot;(#{singular[0,1]})#{singular[...
                          ^
```

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you run that code through MS Word or something? That `&quot;` should have been a `"`. I refuse to believe this loaded and worked in 1.8 in this form.

Comment: How big is the ruby portion of this application? There's a reasonable chance it would be easier to just run `rails new` and "re-write" (lots of copy+pasting)  the whole thing? However, this is also likely to be well beyond the scope of a StackOverflow post --- unless you want to hire a contractor to help out.

Comment: Sergio, I believe you I've never used anything other than MS Expression and Bluefish...but I can't swear I'm the only one to ever touch the code. So maybe you've helped immensely already.

Tom, thanks - I may just do that. BTW, I went back to the original developer to just upgrade the site, but they immediately tried to sell me on a new site - with improved SEO! - for $18k. Which I don't have in the budget.